# How do we show $0$ element is in $\{p \in P(F): p(3) = 0\}$ which is a subset of the vector space of polynomials $P(F)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the closure of $\{p \in P(F): p(3) = 0\}$ under multiplication/addition part. I can't seem to show $0$ is in $\{p \in P(F): p(3) = 0\}$.

Please, help me with that.

Comment: If I take the zero polynomial $f(t) = 0$ and evaluate it at $t = 3$, do I get $0$?

Answer (score 2):

The zero polynomial has the value zero at *every* point, in particular at $x=3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Since $F$ is a field, it certainly has the zero element, and so the zero polynomial is a polynomial over $F$. Now, what value would the zero polynomial have at $x=3$?